# Primefaces Warning

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces. I am trying to add a value from xhtml to back end. The moment I start the server it gives me the warning

```
May 31, 2013 8:56:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2341 ms
May 31, 2013 8:56:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No state saving method defined, assuming default server state saving
```

as a result, none of the functions getting executed. After searching in the forum for a long time, i found something and inserted

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in my `web.xml`. Still same problem.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: did you close the context-param tag?

Comment: @RaghavendaBhat it was not properly formatted.

Comment: Hi, I found the answer myself. Since I couldnot answer my own question as i dont have enough reputations I am including the answer here.

I am having a page which is the index page which just includes other pages. 

    

 
    <h:form>
    <ui:include src="aaa/ddd/fff.xhtml" /></h:form>



like this. SO thats why this warning was coming. Then when I went to the actual page it did not show the warning and everything working perfectly.

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie Ok my mistake

Comment: I don't think it take reputation to answer your own question... you should do it, you find it!

Comment: @Alexaandre Lavoie  done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.  I am having a page which is the index page which just includes other pages.

```
<h:form> <ui:include src="aaa/ddd/fff.xhtml" /></h:form>
```

like this. SO thats why this warning was coming. Then when I went to the actual page it did not show the warning and everything working perfectly.